# df.drop not dropping row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row

I have a for loop that goes through a data frame and asks if we want to delete each row. No matter what I do I cannot get the row to drop if I say Y.

```
import pandas as pd
import random
from csv import writer
import csv

df1 = pd.read_csv('questions.csv', usecols=['question_id','question'])
col1 = df1.question_id
col2 = df1.question

for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    print(row['question'])
    Check1 = input("Is the following question correct? (Y/N): ")
    if Check1 == "Y":
        continue
    elif Check1 == "N":
        Check2 = input("Is this question Needed? (Y/N) ")
        if Check2 == "N":
            Check3 = input("Are you sure you want to Delete this question? (Y/N) ")
            if Check3 == "Y":
                df1.drop(df1.index,inplace=True)
        elif Check2 == "Y":
            Check4 = input("Please rewrite the question: ")
            df1.loc[index, 'question'] = Check4
```

My df is this:
df1 =

```
12,What is your number?
10,What is your email?
6,What is your Job title?
30,What color is your car?
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code except for the **indent** for **if** statement and seems to work perfectly for the given data frame if you **name the columns X and Y**. Can you provide more details of your data frame like column names?

Comment: Updated the question to remove the indent before Check3, i dont have the indents in my code. my column names are ['question_id' , 'question'].

Comment: it seems to working perfectly fine @Parker. I can't exactly pinpoint where the actual problem is from your current explanation. maybe some problem with naming configuration or try resetting the index before iteration if you haven't.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Do you think it is possible that the fact that my dataframe originates from a CSV file?

Comment: Well that should not be a problem if you've used pd.read_csv(). if its possible can you paste the full code that you've tried i.e from reading the data frame to dropping rows?

Comment: I have added the entirety of my code. Thanks for your continued help!

Comment: Replace **df1.drop(df1.index,inplace=True)** in line 20 with **df1.drop(index, inplace=True)**. This should work!

Comment: yeah, this still doesnt work. not sure whats going on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edit] I tried this and it worked for me. Not sure why it's not working for you. Maybe give us your dataframe (or sample of it) to test it.

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['-1', '-2', -3, -4], 'col2':['-2', '-6', 44, 66], 'col3':['15', 16, 17, 29]})
>>> 
>>> for index, row in df1.iterrows():
...     Check3 = input("Are you sure you want to Delete this question? (Y/N) ")
...     if Check3 == "Y":
...       df1.drop(index, inplace=True)
... 
Are you sure you want to Delete this question? (Y/N) Y
Are you sure you want to Delete this question? (Y/N) N
Are you sure you want to Delete this question? (Y/N) Y
Are you sure you want to Delete this question? (Y/N) N
>>> 
>>> df1
  col1 col2 col3
1   -2   -6   16
3   -4   66   29
```

Comment: Sorry - in pasting into the question, I must have added the indent. I dont have an indent in my code. Even still i cannot get the row to drop. My column headers are just ['question_id', 'question']

Answer (score 0):

This code works from me.
***Note:*** I am using the "walrus" operator for python 3.8+

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Questions':[f"Question {i}" for i in range(1,6)],
                   'Text':["What is your number?", "What is your email?",
                           "What is your job title?", "What color is your car?",
                           "Do you have children?"]})
for indx, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row)
    print('\n')
    if (check3 := input("Are you sure you want to delete this row? ") == "Y"):
        df.drop(indx, inplace=True)
    print('\n')
```

Output:

```
Questions              Question 1
Text         What is your number?
Name: 0, dtype: object


Are you sure you want to delete this row? N


Questions             Question 2
Text         What is your email?
Name: 1, dtype: object


Are you sure you want to delete this row? Y


Questions                 Question 3
Text         What is your job title?
Name: 2, dtype: object


Are you sure you want to delete this row? N


Questions                 Question 4
Text         What color is your car?
Name: 3, dtype: object


Are you sure you want to delete this row? N


Questions               Question 5
Text         Do you have children?
Name: 4, dtype: object


Are you sure you want to delete this row? Y
```

And, `print(df)`

```
    Questions                     Text
0  Question 1     What is your number?
2  Question 3  What is your job title?
3  Question 4  What color is your car?
```